# Quality of UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am resizing various images with this func:

```
    func resizeImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        var actualHeight: CGFloat = image.size.height
        var actualWidth: CGFloat = image.size.width

        let maxHeight: CGFloat = 600.0
        let maxWidth: CGFloat = text.frame.size.width - 10

        var imgRatio: CGFloat = actualWidth / actualHeight
        let maxRatio: CGFloat = maxWidth / maxHeight
        let compressionQuality: CGFloat = 0.5
        //50 percent compression
        if actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth {
            if imgRatio < maxRatio {
                //adjust width according to maxHeight
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight
                actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth
                actualHeight = maxHeight
            }
            else if imgRatio > maxRatio {
                //adjust height according to maxWidth
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth
                actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight
                actualWidth = maxWidth
            }
            else {
                actualHeight = maxHeight
                actualWidth = maxWidth
            }
        }
        let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        image.drawInRect(rect)
        let img: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        let imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, compressionQuality)!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return UIImage(data: imageData)!
    }
```

But the quality is just terrible....Heres a picture of what I get bellow:

[image]

I thought the quality of the image varied on what the compressionQuality was...? I have it at 0.5 now as you can see from my code above, but even if I change it to 1 the quality is still terrible?

Any ideas,

Many thanks.

Comment: 0.5 compression ratio to be fit in the original size seems to be a blur effect?

Comment: @zcui93 not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Your code seems to be ok. Could you add original and modified versions of the same image to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)` instead. It will use the correct scale for your device. The version you're using (without options), uses a default scale factor of `1.0`. Using the `...WithOptions()` variant and passing in `0.0` for the scale, defaults to the native scale of the device. Note that this might not be what you want.

Secondly, you can use `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect()` to calculate your target size. Thirdly, you don't need to go through the JPEG encoding, you can return the generated image directly.

Combined, this greatly simplifies your code:

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
  let maxSize = CGSize(
    width: text.frame.size.width - 10, 
    height: 600.0
  )
  let newSize = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(
    image.size, 
    CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: maxSize)
  ).size
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
  image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: newSize))
  let scaled = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
  return scaled
}
```

EDIT: This is an extension on `UIImage` that I use in a project:

```
extension UIImage {
    /**
     Returns an scaled version of self that fits within the provided bounding box.
     It retains aspect ratio, and also retains the rendering mode.
     - parameter size: The target size, in point
     - parameter scale: Optional target scale. If omitted, uses the scale of input image
     - returns: A scaled image
     */
    func imageFittingSize(size: CGSize, scale: CGFloat? = nil) -> UIImage {
        let newSize = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(self.size, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size)).size
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, scale ?? self.scale)
        self.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: newSize))
        let scaled = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return scaled.imageWithRenderingMode(renderingMode)
    }
}
```

You can call it on an image like so:

```
let maxSize = CGSize(width: text.frame.size.width - 10, height: 600.0)
let scaled = image.imageFittingSize(maxSize)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that, I'm guessing I need to install the AVFoundation framework?

Comment: No, it is included in the iOS SDK, but you need to import it at the top of your file.

Comment: Quality looks good, but not the right sizing...http://i.stack.imgur.com/pIjNW.png

Comment: Yeah, the AVFoundation function creates a rect that is centered in the target bounds. Sorry. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ok yeh works now. But I am then uploading the images to Parse, and before the images size would be reduced alot, now the image size is still being reduced but not as much...So it takes a hwile for them to upload. Is there a way to reduce the images size a bit more?

Comment: I don't know how the Parse API works, if you supply it with an UIImage or NSData. But if it is the latter, you can do the JPEG encoding yourself, and possibly save some data. Btw, you shouldn't use Parse, they've announced that they're shutting down.

Comment: Yes, using `image.scale` will use the same scale factor as the input images. That is probably preferable. As I said, using the device scale may not be what you want.

Comment: What makes you think that the image size is in pixels? It is not unless the input image has a scale of 1.0. Also, we only use the input size for its aspect ratio, so the scale is irrelevant. I don't know what OP needs, but in my own use case, I'm scaling an image (of whatever size) to fit a UI component. Using the device scale for the target image is then optimal.

Comment: @SveinHalvorHalvorsen Ah yes, late night brain fart from me there! Although OP hasn't said where exactly his image comes from, so we don't know if it's points or pixels – you're right about only the aspect ratio being important here, my apologies. I have made a trivial edit to your post so I could reverse my downvote :)

Comment: @SveinHalvorHalvorsen I changed this line, added the 1.6, UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.6) And now the quality appears good and the files aren't so big...What do you think?

Comment: A scale of 1.6 seems non-sensical. This means that the pixel size will be 1.6 times the point size of the image in both directions. On a retina device, it's effectively removing about half of the pixels, thus approximately halving the file size. However, you also get half the pixels, so the device would resample it to display it properly. About every other image pixel in either direction would be stretched over two display device pixels. It might work for you, but it's a hack.